# Magento Inactive Module Still Appears In Admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.9

I have been working with Magento for 4 years and only JUST noticed this.  I'm just curious if it's expected behavior.  If you edit a module's XML file and set `<active>` to **false**, that module still appears in the admin under **Advanced -> Disable Modules Output**.  Is this expected behavior?  I'm guessing it has to do with how Magento reads the modules directory to build that list, but it's a bit odd that it would include inactive modules.  If I move or remove the XML file the entry in admin goes away, so it isn't a cache thing.

Comment: Hi Brian I am not the expert like you but my opinion is magento did it intentionally to let user to enable that module from the backend for future ease.The setting of active to false just dosnot include xml's of Config.xml, system.xml and Adminhtml.xml from that module. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Menu you are on is Disable Modules Output.  That menu does not deactivate modules, but instead disables their *output*.  This means a module can still function as normal, but any rendering on the screen would be disabled.

A module can still be disabled and show up on this menu.  This menu gives you an insight into which modules are registered with Magento.  If your module is set to `false`, Magento will not go and load the `config.xml` file that is in your `etc` folder of your module.  It will still show up in this particular list, however.

I hope this helps.